# Save file in a specific dir with QFile.open and Qdir in qt

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qfile, qdir

I was trying to create/save a file in qt creator with QFile.open(). 
But it is always creating/saving files in build folder of application. 
I have tried this code to change the dir to my directory which inside the directory where I have my source/header files.

```
QDir::setCurrent("/ui");
file.setFileName("tmp.ui");

QDir::setCurrent("/main/ui");

if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
{
    builder.save(&file, myDialog);
}
```

It creates the file tmp, but not in right directory. I would like to put relative directory. 
Any idea how I can reach it?

Comment: You should never have to change current directory of your process. It's simply not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really need to change current directory. You can generate absolute file path to file without changing current directory:

```
QDir dir("/main/ui");
file.setFileName(dir.absoluteFilePath("tmp.ui"));
```

However it seems to be pointless too. You can just write `file.setFilename("/main/ui/tmp.ui")`.

Paths starting with '/' are absolute. Are you sure that you have '/ui' or '/main' directories in your filesystem root? It's not likely. Try to specify valid absolute path to `QDir`. If you want to specify relative path, it will be searched from the initial current directory (which can, for example, be the build directory).